# passing array of strings containing float values to POST method

Tags: php, arrays, codenameone

when i pass a string array containing float, latitude and longitude values as argument to ConnectionRequest, at the server side the decimals are stripped leaving only the value before the decimal point.

if i pass an array say: 
    String[] aRR = {"9.0987","9.08796"}
and then add it as request.addArgument("latitude", aRR)

i get at the server side php script these values to be {"9","9"}. What do i do to keep the values consistent

Answer (score 0):

The stripping is done in the PHP side. If you pass this as a string our code can't possibly be aware of the fact that you passed numbers. However, PHP doesn't have a strict type system like Java so if rounding happens it would be on that side.